# Flutter :- Issues in model i've accessed img_path but not able to access image because want to concatenate (img_path+image) to display in home page?

Tags: flutter, carousel, mode

I  want to fetch images from API. I've created a model class but the problem is I have accessed the `img_path` from the model class but am not able to access the image from the model class because I want to concatenate `img_path+image` to display on the home page. Below I've mentioned the model class and home page code. please find and check the below classes.

### Home Page :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'NavDrawer.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

import 'banner_model.dart';

var paddingBottom = 48.0;
var androidDeviceInfo;
var identifier;
var token = "debendra";
var token1;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String apiUrl1 = "https://newbharatbiz.in/mobile_api/v4/all_banner.php";

  Future<BannerModel> fetchAlbum() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl1));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return BannerModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: NavDrawer(),
        appBar:
            AppBar(title: Text('New Bharat Biz'), centerTitle: true, actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ]),
        body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          FutureBuilder<BannerModel>(
            future: fetchAlbum(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final List<String> imagesList = [
                  snapshot.data!.imgPath + "1542696267.png"
                ];
                return Container(
                  child: CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 330,
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      viewportFraction: 0.8,
                      initialPage: 0,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                      reverse: false,
                      autoPlay: true,
                      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    ),
                    items: imagesList
                        .map(
                          (item) => Container(
                            child: Center(
                                child: Image.network(item,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                );
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 16,
                  height: 16,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

### Model Class :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final bannerModel = bannerModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

BannerModel bannerModelFromJson(String str) => BannerModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String bannerModelToJson(BannerModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class BannerModel {
  BannerModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.imgPath,
    required this.banner,
  });

  int status;
  String imgPath;
  List<Banner> banner;

  factory BannerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BannerModel(
    status: json["status"],
    imgPath: json["img_path"],
    banner: List<Banner>.from(json["Banner"].map((x) => Banner.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "img_path": imgPath,
    "Banner": List<dynamic>.from(banner.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}
 class Banner {
  Banner({
    required this.id,
    required this.type,
    required this.parentId,
    required this.title,
    required this.caption,
    required this.image,
    required this.link,
    required this.status,
    required this.sliderOrder,
    required this.entryTime,
  });

  String id;
  String type;
  String parentId;
  String title;
  String caption;
  String image;
  String link;
  String status;
  String sliderOrder;
  DateTime entryTime;

  factory Banner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Banner(
    id: json["id"],
    type: json["type"],
    parentId: json["parent_id"],
    title: json["title"],
    caption: json["caption"],
    image: json["image"],
    link: json["link"],
    status: json["status"],
    sliderOrder: json["slider_order"],
    entryTime: DateTime.parse(json["entry_time"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "type": type,
    "parent_id": parentId,
    "title": title,
    "caption": caption,
    "image": image,
    "link": link,
    "status": status,
    "slider_order": sliderOrder,
    "entry_time": entryTime.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. If you are getting the image from an API, why do you need to concatenate? Is your images saved in local and you just get the image path from api?

Comment: {
    "status": 1,
    "img_path": "https://newbharatbiz.in/admin/upload/banner/",
    "Banner": [
        {
            "id": "37",
            "type": "top",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "title": "newbanner1june2",
            "caption": "nnn",
            "image": "1542696267.png",
            "link": "https://newbharatbiz.in/",
            "status": "1",
            "slider_order": "4",
            "entry_time": "2021-03-06 12:52:47"
        }
     
    ]
}

Comment: so where is this png image stored? is it stored locally?

Comment: please check my api responses i want to concatenate img_path+image to display in home page . have accessed img_path but not able to access image to concatenate

Comment: @Kamrul Hasan Jony i want to concatenate because my api structure showing in different key image and img_path  please look up my API responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to show images in the Banner. So you should populate your imagesList like this:

```
List<String> imagesList = [];
snapshot.data!.banner.foreach((e) {
   imagesList.add(snapshot.data!.imgPath+"/"+e.image);
});
```

Comment: Thankx yes it worked for me but image is'nt showing in CarouselSlider.